# Use a PHP script and cron to delete files in a directory over x days old

Tags: php, cron

I have looked around this site and others to find a simple php script that I can use with cron to remove files over X days old in a directory.  There seem to be plenty but none work for me.  I am on a shared server (G C Solutions) and the hosters are great but the packageI am on does not include shell access so I don't think I can use .sh or bash commands.

I have a neat php script to do a Mysqldump of my database, copy it to a directory in my home area ( /home/mysite/backups ) and send me a copy via email - this all works fine.  Now I was trying to run a script that would just leave 5 days worth of backups in the backups diretory. I am trying this script at present:-

```
<?php


$dir = opendir('/home/mysite/backups");
if ($dir) {

        // Read directory contents
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {

        // Check the create time of each file (older than 5 days)
        if (filemtime($file) < (time() - 60*60*24*5)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

It doesn't work, my cron setting string is :- 
php -q /home/mysite/public_html/scripts/delold6.php

I've tried running it from above the the html_public, no joy, the backup directory rights are set to 755, when my backup script copies the dump to this directory files are set at 644.  I have tried chmoding these to 777 - no joy.  Can anyone help here.  *find /path/to/your_directory -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;* does not work from cron either.

Comment: Have you tried instead of your final IF to put `echo $file."\r\n";` ? Do you see a list of all the files?

Comment: you've either got a php error or a error when copy&pasting this question @ `opendir('/home/mysite/backups");`

Comment: What is the owner and group of `backups` folder ?

Comment: single quote and double quote ... they don't mix like that

Comment: opendir('/home/mysite/backups"); change to opendir('/home/mysite/backups');

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with bash only. No need for php:

```
 find /your/directory -type f -mmin +720 -exec rm {} \;
```

--mmin parameter is file age in minutes

If you are on a shared server you could still try to execute this with shell_exec(), most hosters allow this

Also you forgot to skip '.' and '..' in the loop